# Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found with GearVR Framework

Tags: android, frameworks, gear-vr

Recently started working with Android Studio, I would like to build one of the demos of the GearVRFramework (https://github.com/gearvrf/GearVRf-Demos).

I have successfully built my framework in Android, but when I try to open one of the demo sample, I always get this error : **Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found.**

I think its related to the structure of my project, and the fact that I have two graddle configurations. I tried different configurations by ordering my folders in different ways but still, I can't find the error.

Here is my projects folders organization : 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDnVb.png

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Look at the `settings.gradle` file:

```
include ':framework'
include ':app'
project(':framework').projectDir = new File('../../GearVRf/GVRf/Framework/framework')
```

Gradle say that it can't load a module (the error message is not very clear...).

Do you have `'../../GearVRf/GVRf/Framework/framework'` directory from your project?
If not, try to adapt the path.

Comment: Here is my folders organization with the framework, I have carefully followed the instructions on the GearVrFramework Demos project on github : http://i.stack.imgur.com/iwuZK.png